# Android OpenCV Fatal Signal 11,(bad coding practices?)

Tags: android, c++, opencv

There really isn't that much documentation on the dreaded Fatal Signal 11 of OpenCV. Can someone familiar with OpenCV provide a thorough explanation of what causes it? It seems like it could be due to the 'Android OpenCV binding' in some cases, but in mine, I am not sure that's necessarily true.

Though repetitive calls to the Log, I've narrowed down the exact point where I often hit a Fatal Signal 11.It comes before a gigantic for loop, shown below. I'm assuming it's a memory issue since the program runs this function for about 5-30 seconds before crashing with this error. I'm a self-taught coder, so generally if something works I stick with it, but that makes it difficult for me to know when my code is being efficient or inefficient. In this particular case it seems to be causing an error in C++ code that I don't know how to debug.

```
    int cols = myimage.cols; int rows = myimage.rows;
    for (int y = 0; y < cols; y++){
    for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++){
        //val1 = g4.at<float>(y, x);
        //val2 = g5.at<float>(y, x);
        if (g4.at<float>(y, x) >= minrad && g5.at<float>(y, x) >= minrad){
            if (g4.at<float>(y, x) <= maxrad && g5.at<float>(y, x) <= maxrad){
                if (((x + g4.at<float>(y, x)) <= rows) && (y + g5.at<float>(y, x) <= cols)){
                    mapped.at<float>(y + g5.at<float>(y, x) , y + g4.at<float>(y, x)) =              mapped.at<float>(y + g5.at<float>(y, x), y + g4.at<float>(y, x)) + 1;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The full error message is (shown in Eclipse -- Is there a way for me to garner more information on this error? I tried adb logcat a few days ago but I'm not sure whether the information it gave me was anymore useful):

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x62bacfb4 (code=1), thread 24457 (Thread-475)
```

If someone could leave a comment explaining exactly what this error message means, that would help me too.

Comment: y should go over rows, x over cols ;)   (and change your bounds checking-code, too)

Comment: Did you mean to fix my code because you just did

Answer (score 1):

Signal 11 is a segfault.  It means something accessed memory that wasn't allocated to the program by the OS.  Given the address it occurred at, it looks like someone either went past the bounds of an array or accessed a pointer that was never initialized.  Figuring out more is impossible without a crash trace.